# SNMPv3 context on IOS-XE does not seem to work with Prime

Tags: cisco-ios, snmp, cisco-ios-15, ios-xe, snmpv3

We recently switched to SNMPV3 and experience the issue, that there is no client data available within prime anymore. So we quickly read about the SNMP context we need to add to our devices configuration in order for prime to get the correct data back. This works well for IOS. But we didnt have any luck with IOS-XE so far.
This is the configuration that works on our 2960X models:

```
snmp-server group COMPANY v3 priv context vlan- match prefix read COMPANY
```

When we issue the show snmp group and context, we get:

```
switch#show snmp group 
groupname: COMPANY                          security model:v3 priv 
contextname: <no context specified>         storage-type: nonvolatile
readview : COMPANY                          writeview: <no writeview specified>        
notifyview: <no notifyview specified>       
row status: active

groupname: COMPANY                          security model:v3 priv 
contextname: vlan-                          storage-type: nonvolatile
readview : COMPANY                          writeview: <no writeview specified>        
notifyview: <no notifyview specified>       
row status: active

switch#show snmp context 
vlan-1
vlan-10
vlan-11
vlan-20
```

So if we check the configuration for IOS-XE, it looks the same, but it does simply not work. There are no clients that are connected to any IOS-XE devices visible in prime. We have different model switches like: Cisco Catalyst 3850 and 9200. We tried it with an context per Vlan, but this did not help as well:

```
snmp-server group COMPANY v3 priv context vlan-1 read COMPANY 
snmp-server group COMPANY v3 priv context vlan-10 read COMPANY 
snmp-server group COMPANY v3 priv context vlan-11 read COMPANY 
snmp-server group COMPANY v3 priv context vlan-20 read COMPANY 

switch#show snmp group                   
groupname: COMPANY                          security model:v3 priv 
contextname: <no context specified>         storage-type: nonvolatile
readview : COMPANY                          writeview: <no writeview specified>        
notifyview: <no notifyview specified>       
row status: active

groupname: COMPANY                          security model:v3 priv 
contextname: vlan-1                         storage-type: nonvolatile
readview : COMPANY                          writeview: <no writeview specified>        
notifyview: <no notifyview specified>       
row status: active

groupname: COMPANY                          security model:v3 priv 
contextname: vlan-10                        storage-type: nonvolatile
readview : COMPANY                          writeview: <no writeview specified>        
notifyview: <no notifyview specified>       
row status: active

groupname: COMPANY                          security model:v3 priv 
contextname: vlan-11                        storage-type: nonvolatile
readview : COMPANY                          writeview: <no writeview specified>        
notifyview: <no notifyview specified>       
row status: active

groupname: COMPANY                          security model:v3 priv 
contextname: vlan-20                        storage-type: nonvolatile
readview : COMPANY                          writeview: <no writeview specified>        
notifyview: <no notifyview specified>       
row status: active

switch#show snmp context 
vlan-1
vlan-10
vlan-11
vlan-20
```

I tried to use the default readview, as i have seen some configuration use v1default:

```
snmp-server group COMPANY v3 priv read COMPANY
snmp-server group COMPANY v3 priv context vlan- match prefix 

switch#show snmp group 
groupname: COMPANY                          security model:v3 priv 
contextname: <no context specified>         storage-type: nonvolatile
readview : COMPANY                          writeview: <no writeview specified>        
notifyview: <no notifyview specified>       
row status: active

groupname: COMPANY                          security model:v3 priv 
contextname: vlan-                          storage-type: nonvolatile
readview : v1default                        writeview: <no writeview specified>        
notifyview: <no notifyview specified>       
row status: active
```

Nothing helped so far. I couldnt find anyone with the same issue online, so thats why I put this in here. If someone could give the correct string (OID) that prime uses I could probably test this with an SNMP client to see if the response is different between the two operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix for this. The trick is not to put the read community in the command. So we deployed this to all the IOS and IOS-XE switches and it works for all Vlans:

```
snmp-server group COMPANY v3 priv context vlan- match prefix
```

There was a strange timing issue within prime as well that made it difficult to verify the configuration.

Comment: I have the same issue and the solution above does nothing. On the other switch with the same IOS-XE version the same configuration works fine. Go figure.